# How to restore a place holder in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I saved a model in tensorflow and I would like to restore it for further use, but I got an error. The code is somehow like follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def input_func(dim):
    input_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,dim])
    return input_
def fully_connect(input_,out_dimension):
    out=tf.layers.dense(input_, out_dimension,\
        kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer(uniform=False))
    return tf.reduce_sum(out)
def train(real_input, input_dim, out_dimension):
    input_ = input_func(input_dim)
    output = fully_connect(input_, out_dimension)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        for epoch in range(10):
            sess.run(output, {input_:real_input})

        tf.add_to_collection('input_',input_)
        tf.add_to_collection('output',output)
        tf.train.Saver().save(sess,'./save/expression') 
dim=3
out_dimension=2
real_input=[[1,2,3]]
with tf.Graph().as_default():
    train(real_input, dim, out_dimension)
```

Now the model is built and saved.

Later to restore the model I used the following code:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./save/expression.ckpt.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, './save/expression.ckpt')
    input_=tf.get_collection('input_')
    print(input_)
    output=tf.get_collection('output')
    print(sess.run(output, {input_:[[4,5,6]]}))
```

But I encounter an error:

```
INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from ./save/expression.ckpt
[]

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-98-6cfbdc96438e> in <module>()
      5     print(input_)
      6     output=tf.get_collection('output')
----> 7     print(sess.run(output, {input_:[[4,5,6]]}))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

It seems that the placeholder input_ is not saved!

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: Placeholders cannot be saved.

Comment: @SiyuanRen: is this comment accurate? The accepted answer involves restoring a saved placeholder.

Comment: @MonicaHeddneck: Depends on how you define "save" and "load". Placeholders are stored in the graph definition, not checkpoints, so if you think reading the graph is loading, then it can be saved and loaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to restore the placeholder and feed it its appropriate value. Ideally you should have named your placeholder when you created it. Since you haven't named it, you have to find the name from your graph.
After the model is restored, print out the name of nodes in your graph, the placeholder will be printed first.
You can do this with

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./save/expression.ckpt.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, './save/expression.ckpt')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    for op in graph.get_operations():
        print(op.name)
```

I guess that the input placeholder will be given the default name "Placeholder".
After you find its name you have to restore that tensor and feed it a value.
If name is `Placeholder`, you can restore it with

`graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')`

You should locate the name of your output node in the same manner. It should be something like `fully_connected_1/matmul...`, let's assume the name to be outputNodeName.
Then you can run your graph as

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    loader = tf.train.import_meta_graph('./save/expression.ckpt.meta')
    loader.restore(sess, './save/expression.ckpt')
    graph = tf.get_default_graph()
    input_= graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')
    output=tf.get_collection('outputNodeName:0')
    print(sess.run(output, {input_:[[4,5,6]]}))
```